# How can use a variable of Javascript in the "style" of tag?

Tags: javascript, css

i need create this function to improve my code.
I need give to the  a color given by the caller of the function, how can i do this?

Here the code:

```
function visualizza(array, div, color)
{
    div.html("");
    div.append("<p>");

    array.forEach(function (e)
    {
        div.append
        (
            "<span style='color: (here i need the variable)'>" + e.nominativo + "   Tel: "+e.cellulare+"</span><br>"
        )
    });

    div.append("</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use concatenation like the rest of your js variables

```
"<span style='color: "+color+"'>" + e.nominativo + "   Tel: "+e.cellulare+"</span><br>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `template literals` which is a feature of ES2015. It enables you to inject variables into a string.

```
`<span style='color: ${yourColor}'>${e.nominativo} Tel: ${e.cellulare}</span><br>`
```

**NOTE**: This feature is not compatible with all browsers.

Comment: For information to users who might stumble upon this: https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals